# LED_INTENSITY - controlling a led by a RF transmitter

Tags: voltage, led, amperage, led-driver

More precisely this transmitter: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/368/Si4012-35123.pdf

On page 34 there is

```
> 5.2.3. PROPERTY: LED_INTENSITY Purpose: LED current drive strength 
> Property: 0x11 
> Default: 0x00 
> Fields: LedIntensity [1:0]—LED intensity
> 00: LED off
> 01: 0.37 mA 
> 10: 0.60 mA 
> 11: 0.97 mA
```

Page 8 (Typical Application Schematic) shows how they connect the LED to the appropriate pin - no resistor (!)

I think I am missing a few things;

- first there is the Ampere stepping for led intensity - should it not be a Volt scale ?
- secondly 0.xx mA seems quite low. I was unable to find any LEDs working at that sort of amperage. Perhaps there is an error and they meant 37 / 60 / 97 mA ?

How do these led drivers work really ?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a receiver somewhere?

Comment: With a hi-bright LED, doing voltage pulsing.

Comment: Nope, a low power led will work at 0.37 mA, just not very bright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LED brightness is controlled by current, not voltage. In a LED-resistor combo, the voltage (minus the LED forward drop) actually controls the current flow. This device provides a current-controlled output so no resistor is required.

As for the low available current on that pin, many small SMD indicator LEDs will provide sufficient light output at 1ma, Such as [this](http://www.rohm.com/web/global/datasheet/SML-P11MT(R)), which I found with a very quick Digikey search.